# SAPUI5 Bar Code Scanner App on FIORI Client - Camera opens but scan does not gives the result

Tags: sapui5, barcode, barcode-scanner, sap-fiori

I have created a SAPUI5 app for bar code scanner using cordova plugin.
When I deploy it on FIORI Launchpad and try to run the app. then the camera opens to read the bar code but it does not gives the result of the scanned code.
Any help please?
Following are the screen shots & Codes of my project on Eclipse.
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIyTy.jpg)

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>
    <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
    </script>

    <script>
            sap.ui.localResources("barcodenew");
            var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"idMain1"});
            var page = sap.ui.view({id:"idMain1", 
                                    viewName:"barcodenew.Main",
                                    type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});   
            app.addPage(page);
            app.placeAt("content");
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"> </script>
</head>
<body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**View.xml**

```
<core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="barcodenew.Main"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<Page title="ISPC Asset BarCode">
    <content>
        <Label text="BarCode" class="sapUiSmallMargin" />
        <Input id="BCID" width="150px" value="12345"/>
        <Button id="BC" text="" 
                icon="sap-icon://camera" 
                press="handleCamera" type="Accept" />

    </content>
</Page>
</core:View>
```

**Controller.js**

```
sap.ui.controller("barcodenew.Main", {

handleCamera: function(evt){
    var bc = this.getView().byId("BCID");

    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
            function(result){
                bc.setValue(result.text);                   
            },
            function(error){
                alert("Sorry, Camera Error!!"+error);
            }

        );
},
});
```

[Camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1cTh.jpg)

Regards,
Firoz.

Comment: Yes, it works standalone without FIORI launchpad when the same code is pushed as apk file to my android device.

Comment: Hi 'SAP Fiori Crew', I have gone through all the help links that you have mentioned. In fact I have used Renald's blog as my starting point for this project. All these blogs mentions building the code in Eclipse/WebIDE and then copying it to the Cordova project. This works perfectly fine for me also as I mentioned earlier(standalone works fine). However, my requirement is the other way round. Taking the files from cordova project and copying it to my SAPUI5 app and then running it on FIORI Launchpad.Unfortunately this does not returns me the data. Would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Yes, I have tried on other device as well and with different barcodes also the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

In [Fiori Launchpad inside the Fiori Client - use cordova/Kapsel plugins](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3760016) they mention

"Add windows.parent before cordova to reach the launchpad level."
Maybe

```
window.parent.cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan
```

instead of

```
cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan
```

can help you.
I don't have a FLP to try it. So I don't know, if it really works.